# Fixing the much dreaded "A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when 'N : equality' " error

Tags: .net, f#, constraints

This bit of code:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type INode =
    interface
        inherit IEqualityComparer<INode>
        inherit IEquatable<INode>
    end

let myFun<'N when 'N :> INode> (n:'N) = n = n
```

generates the following build error:

```
A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when 'N : equality'
```

I know I can appease the compiler at the function level with

```
let myFun<'N when 'N :> INode and 'N : equality> (n:'N) = n = n
```

but I'd prefer to let the type constraint as it was in `myFun` and "fix" the issue at `INode`, so as to make it easier in case I want to have several functions taking on the very same constraint.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the bit inside the `<>` which makes the problem go away when it is removed:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type INode =
    interface
        inherit IEqualityComparer<INode>
        inherit IEquatable<INode>
    end

let myFun (n:'N when 'N :> INode) = n = n
```

An even simpler version (from @ben) is to use the shorthand for types which are downcastable as follows:

```
let myFun (n: #INode) = n = n
```

Comment: Cool. But how would I then deal with the following case : "let myFun<'N when 'N :> INode> (a:'N) (b:'N) = a = b" ?

Comment: @devouredelysium This works just fine: `let myFun (n:'N when 'N :> INode) (b:'N) = n = b`

Comment: Even better would be `let myFun (n: #INode) = n`, which is shorthand for the above.